# Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/simpleframework/xml/Attribute

Tags: android, dex

I am implementing C2Call library for dial call purpose in one application, and C2Call library has lots of jar files, simple-xml-2.6.7.jar is part of C2Call library.
simple-xml-2.6.7.jar is giving me an error in my application at compile time:

> [2014-08-21 11:09:56 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/simpleframework/xml/Attribute;
>   [2014-08-21 11:09:56 ] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/simpleframework/xml/Attribute;

I've done a lot of surfing to solve this problem, but I can not find solution to resolve this problem.

I hope, you can give solution for this problem.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem happens if you are importing the same library in two different jars. You need to carefully check all the jars and try to find out the jars which are importing the same libraries. If you have the source code then you can easily build the jar again without adding the library.

Another thing to try is to break it into multiple dex files. Please read from here

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/07/custom-class-loading-in-dalvik.html

"Big apps can contain more than 64K method references, which is the maximum number of supported in a dex file. To get around this limitation, developers can partition part of the program into multiple secondary dex files, and load them at runtime."

I think you have more than 64k method references and that is causing the problem. Let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank You Sir. I will do this process as you can suggest me.

Comment: Hello sir, I done this process, now another error occur at compile time.

Comment: [Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: The above errors are occurd at compile time, please help me sir.

Comment: Can you mail me the complete log trace?

Comment: Compile Error:                                                              [Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536      It gives me only 2 line error not more error.

Comment: sir, can you give your mail id,so i will send mail to your mail id

Answer (score 1):

It happens when you try to export same jar file twice in single .apk file.
Simple way to eliminate this error

Check your:-
Android private libraries
Referenced Libraries
Android Dependencies

and make sure that no jar file is repeated.If any jar file is repeated then find it in libs folder of your project and delete it and then refresh the project.

If this does not solve then try:-

Right Click Project>Properties>Java Build path>Order and Export> uncheck android private Libraries.

Comment: Thanks sir, I will do this process.

Comment: Hello sir, I done this process, now another error occur at compile time.           [Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536 Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536              The above errors are occurd at compile time, please help me sir.

Comment: The meaning of this error is your apk file has methods more than 65536.I think you are trying to use methods of higher api level in the low api level.If you are testing it on the device then you must check that device has latest android api level.

Comment: Thanks sir,My App Api level is 19., and i testing my app on higher level device.My Device vesrion is 4.2.1 .

Comment: Sorry Sir, I tried your solution in my app, but app generate same error

Comment: Sir, I accept your one solution, "The meaning of this error is your apk file has methods more than 65536.", but I can't remove any methods. because, All Methods are important for this app., I already removed unnecessary methods.

Comment: I think you should not worry about removing unnecessary methods in your application because you cannot actually write 65536 methods by your own,some library is messing up during the compile time.Put your logcat in verbose mode and then check which file is actually messing up. There is a selector list in the logcat window select "VERBOSE" this will help you find exactly where and in which file the error is occuring then you can easily rectify that error.and you better post here that part of log where error is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

I added MobFox simple-xml-2.7.1.jar file to Android lib file. When i generated apk i have this error. Delete simple-xml-2.7.1.jar after regenerate apk. I solved my problem by this way.