# Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d - opencv Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv, android-studio

OpenCV error from imported project.
How can i resolve the following error, I m unable to resolve for past 2 days and searched lot regarding . I used to import this project ([Project](https://github.com/noureldien/FingerprintRecognition/tree/master/Java))and getting error.
**

> [2016-05-30 16:36:44 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex
>   files define Lorg/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d; [2016-05-30 16:36:44 -
>   SplashActivity] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute
>   dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d;

**

I have tried removing and adding the library file. and clean build , eclipse restart and so on. nothing solves here.

when i run it shows this first and the above:
Android Launch:
Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running application.
In Android Stuido:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':java:packageAllDebugClassesForMultiDex'.
>
> > java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/opencv/calib3d/Calib3d.class

**Update:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.fingerprintrecognition"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 15

        ndk {
            moduleName "nonfree_prebuilt"
        }
    }
    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
    }
    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':openCVLibrary2411')
    compile files('libs/opencv-2.4.9-5.jar')
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show us your `build.gradle` file?

Comment: @ishmaelMakitla kindly see my build.gradle file

Comment: Try setting `multiDexEnabled false` - also move your dependencies to the app-level `build.gradle` file. By the way, can you show the app-level gradle file as well?

Comment: can u elaborate this refers -  dependencies to the app-level build.gradle file ? @ishmaelMakitla this above gradle file is app/gradle file

Comment: OK, noted. I suspect the issue might be that you are importing the same library `opencv` in two places - for instance if the `libs` folder is part of your project - this might confuse things as to which lib/jar to look at. Did you perhaps add the `opencv-2.4.9-5.jar` through the "configure buildpath" route?

Comment: I think ur rite that i m using two libs.. Actually i dont add library file i used to import from that project that only .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This often happens when you import one library/jar multiple times. Please make sure you are not importing the `opencv-2.4.9-5.jar` from multiple places. It might also happen that one of the other libraries also imports this library - so you need to check that as well.

Have a look at a closely related issue and the selected answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25419124/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lorg-simpleframework-xml-attrib?rq=1).

Hope this helps you resolve the issue.